# Passing an Object reference to a Util Class

Tags: java

I am working on a Web based application based on Java EE.

My question: I am creating an instance of `BaseAPI` and passing it to a utility class called `BaseUtil` as shown below:

```
package com ;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BaseAPI bApi = new BaseAPI();
        BaseUtil.getData(bApi);

    }

}



public class BaseUtil {

public static String getData(BaseAPI bapi) {

        bapi.addAccountIdParameter("SIM1");
        bapi.getData();
        return null;
    }
}




package com;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class BaseAPI {
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    public void addAccountIdParameter(String value) {
        addParameter("ID", value);
    }
    public void addParameter(String name, String value) {
        if ((name != null) && (value != null)) {
            params.put(name.trim().toLowerCase(), value.trim());
        }
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return "";
    }

}
```

This is working fine. Please let me know if this is a valid approach or it will have any negative impact anywhere?

Comment: What negative impact do you fear?

Comment: As long as your helper classes add value to your operations I see no problem. Just don't over-rely on helpers to do the job ot you'll end up with spread logic that will make your app really hard to mantain. Keep your helpers cohesive and avoid using them as a base for business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid approach and in the general will have no negative impacts.  However, significantly more information would be required to understand if its the best choice for your API.  One recommendation:

Make the constructor of your BaseUtil class private:

```
public class BaseUtil {
    private BaseUtil(){}
    ...
}
```

This will prevent your other classes from creating objects of this class if it is merely a static utility class.  Also, if you start to add fields to this BaseUtil class, you'll need to start thinking about thread safety if your application will be multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

From a runtime perspective, the approach looks fine, it shouldn't cause any performance or memory issues if you are referring to these.

From a more general design perspective, it looks awkward and I would recommend against doing that. Your `BaseAPI` class (and the name already hints at that) looks like a public API, but in your case, the `BaseAPI` instance is also storing state in the form of the parameter. The `BaseAPI` class looks more like a DAO instead, which you could easily implement in a stateless matter:

```
public class BaseAPI {
    public String getData(Map<String, Object> params)
    {
        // Do your parameter mapping here, then fetch the data
        return "";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, provide the ID parameter as a method parameter.

Bundle that with some dependency injection mechanism like *Spring*, and your design will be a lot cleaner.